# Special characters in bulk insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I need to pass this query :

```
BULK INSERT e-Alexie.ENTREPRISE\beulin-ma.Correspondance_RCU_PP
FROM '\\ST077283\C:\Users\P20M511\Documents\Test_RCU.csv';
```

but I get an error on the `-` character. I've tried with `^_-^_` but it didn't work

Any idea?

Comment: It's unclear what you want your destination to be; that name is not a valid name on its own. `BULK INSERT` can only insert locally, so you'll have to use `[database].[schema].[table]` (no server name), where you can escape names containing special characters with `[]`. What's more, your UNC path is not valid; it should be ``\\ST077283\C\`` or ``\\ST077283\C$\`` (depending on whether the C share is public or not).

Comment: *I've tried with `^_-^_` but it didn't work* - did you try with `o_O` instead? That usually makes my database behave but sometimes it just says `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` :)

Comment: Do you *really* have a database called `e-Alexie` and a schema called `ENTREPRISE\beulin-ma`? If so, you'll have to delimit identify those names, however, I suggest changing the names to ones that doesn't require quoting.

Comment: @Larnu feels like this is an attempt to bulk insert over a DB link?

Comment: I suspect the OP's lack of explanation of what they are *Actually* trying to do would tell us all, @CaiusJard .